# Specifying IP addresses that can connect to an app in Bluemix with Secure Gateway

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I am using the Secure Gateway service in Bluemix and I need to restrict access to my app. How do I include a white list of IP addresses? How do I exclude a black list of IP addresses? I am unable to find this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add IP addresses to the white list by accessing a destination's "Advanced options" dropdown. Look under "Network options", and select "Restrict network access to cloud endpoint" as shown in the picture here.
[image]

Comment: Thank you letting me know how to include a list of IP addresses. That helps! Does anyone know how to exclude a list of IP addresses too?